# Windows SDK Configuration Tool Can't See Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration, sdk

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 and the Windows SDK 7.0. I want Visual Studio 2010 to use Windows SDK 7.0 instead of Windows SDK 7.1 (or another SDK). So I ran the Windows SDK Configuration Tool and it shows 'select visual studio versions'. But it only has two options, Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008, nothing about 2010..

Comment: Try "Workarounds" tab at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564354/winsdk-7-1-net-4-windows-sdk-configuration-tool-fails-with-only-vs2010-installed

Comment: By Windows SDK Configuration Tool you mean "WindowsSdkVer.exe", right?